# Generator function behaves differently in various iteration contexts

Tags: python-3.x

So I have this generator function for non-recursive permutations, when I use it in for loop, I get what I expect:

```
>>> for p in permutate3( "abc" ): print( p )
...
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'c', 'b']
['b', 'a', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'a']
['c', 'a', 'b']
['c', 'b', 'a']
```

But once I use it in list or print with argument unpacking I get this strange output:

```
>>> list( permutate3( "abc" ) )
[['c', 'b', 'a'], ['c', 'b', 'a'], ['c', 'b', 'a'], ['c', 'b', 'a'], ['c', 'b', 'a'], ['c', 'b', 'a']]
>>> print( *permutate3( "abc" ) )
['c', 'b', 'a'] ['c', 'b', 'a'] ['c', 'b', 'a'] ['c', 'b', 'a'] ['c', 'b', 'a'] ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

Why does this happen?..

The function itself is:

```
def permutate3( s ):
    l = len( s )
    taken = [ False ] * l
    permutation = [ None ] * l
    current = 0
    stack = [ 0 ]

    while True:
        while stack[-1] < l:
            if not taken[ stack[-1] ]:
                permutation[current] = s[ stack[-1] ]
                if current == l-1:
                    yield permutation
                else:
                    taken[ stack[-1] ] = True
                    stack.append( 0 )
                    current+=1
                    break
            stack[-1]+=1
        else:
            stack.pop()
            if len( stack ) == 0:
                break
            else:
                current-=1
                taken[ stack[-1] ] = False
                stack[-1]+=1
                continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Dummy me. My function yields reference to the same object every time, which is changed by the function for subsequent permutations. Obviously it should be yield list( permutation ).

Answer (score 0):

I don't See the reason for this behavior exactly, but please try to change

```
permutation = [ None ] * l
```

into

```
permutation = [None for _ in range(l)]
```

In the First example, all Elements of the List are the Same object while in the second example there will be different objects.

Comment: I understood the problem. My function yields ref to the same list object every time, which is changed for subsequent permutation. Dummy me.